# Existence of Rotation-Type Unitary Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem

If $ x $ and $y$ are points in $n$-dimensional complex space and $|x| = |y|$, then construct unitary matrix $U$ such that $Ux=y$.

It seems trivial that the rotation type unitary matrix will work, but I cannot formulate it in a matrix in complex n-dimensional space. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may as well assume $|x| = |y| = 1$. Try to construct orthonormal bases $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ with $x_1 = x$ and $y_1 = y$. The matrices $X = [x_1|\cdots|x_n]$ and $Y = [y_1|\cdots|y_n]$ are unitary, so $U = YX^{-1}$ is too, and $Ux = Y (X^{-1}x_1) = Y e_1 = y_1 = y$ where $e_1$ is the standard first basis vector.